# Picasso FileNotFoundException image from contacts in Jetpack compose

Tags: image, android-jetpack-compose, uri, drawable, picasso

While using the picasso library to get a contact avatar from a uri I get the following error:

```
FileNotFoundException content://com.android.contacts/contacts/141/photo
```

A similar implementation in Java with the same uri works fine.
In Java I'm loading the uri directly with imageview field but in jetpack I'm using Target.

```kotlin
var image by remember { mutableStateOf<ImageBitmap?>(null) }
val uri = viewModel.getAvatarUri().get(neme)?.get()
var drawable by remember { mutableStateOf<Drawable?>(null) }
DisposableEffect(uri) {
    val picasso = Picasso.get()

    val target = object : Target {
        override fun onPrepareLoad(placeHolderDrawable: Drawable?) {
            drawable = placeHolderDrawable
        }

        override fun onBitmapFailed(e: Exception?, errorDrawable: Drawable?) {
            println(e) //error
            drawable = errorDrawable
        }

        override fun onBitmapLoaded(bitmap: Bitmap?, from: Picasso.LoadedFrom?) {
            image = bitmap?.asImageBitmap()
        }
    }

    picasso
        .load(uri)
        .placeholder(R.drawable.person)
        .into(target)

    onDispose {
        image = null
        drawable = null
        picasso.cancelRequest(target)
    }
}

Image(
    image!!, contentDescription = "Avatar",
    modifier = Modifier
        .size(48.dp)
        .background(Color.Gray, CircleShape)
)
```

Answer (score 1):

"Nobody works on Picasso. If you want something in the next N years definitely use Coil. Or Glide. Or whatever. They're all fine." - Jake Wharton

https://github.com/square/picasso/issues/2203